# Moving part of equation to next line

Tags: formatting, equations

I have an equation:

```
\begin{equation}
MMAV1 = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N \omega_n|x_n|, \\
\omega_n =
\begin{cases}
1 & if 0.25N \leq n \leq 0.75N \\
0.5 & otherwise \\
\end{cases}
\label{equ:MMAV1}
\end{equation}
```

and I want the cases to be displayed on the next line.
I have tried using \begin{align} but that splits it into two equations with two reference numbers.

Does somebody know how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aligned instead of align environment

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\text{MMAV1} &= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N \omega_n|x_n|\,, \\
\omega_n &=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $0.25N \leq n \leq 0.75N$} \\
0.5 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\,.
\end{aligned}
\label{equ:MMAV1}
\end{equation}
```

Of course, you can ommit the `\\` after `\omega_n`, if you do not want only the cases to be in a different line.

Also the split environment can do the trick (same use).

Both of the above need the `amsmath` package.

Comment: Ah yes. It is as simple as that. I wonder why it did not auto complete to "aligned" for me when I started typing "\begin{align...".  Also, what does the & do in front of the equal sign that you added?

Comment: @Sigmundur the & sign in the first equation set a "column" where every other & will be placed. In the above example, the two equal signs will be the one under the other. Try to move the first & before \sum to see the difference, or the second one before \begin.

Comment: i don't think you want the ``\\`` after the `\omega_n` on the second line.  and there also needs to be an `\end{equation]` since that environment has been begun.

Comment: Ah yes. I see now. It aligns the two equal signs just like in the cases to keep them aligned. @barbara beeton correct. I don't want it and thus have removed it. Ending the equation was a given :)   Thanks for the help. Now I have everything I need for my equations to be properly formatted. :)

Comment: @barbara beeton you are right for the \end{equation}. However, I tried to change the examlpe that Sigmundur asked and to do exactly what he asked for (I want the cases to be displayed on the next line). I commented the other issues right after my example.